# Searching part of string in another string

Tags: java

I am trying find a string within another string using below code , but it is not working.If it is not correct,Please let me know which method string to 
use.

```
String infoException="Could not connect to Item interfacecom.clns.exception.ItemNotFoundException: Could not find Item data";

String keys="ItemNotFoundException";

if(keys.contains(infoException))

 System.out.println("Exception found");
```

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 3):

It should be :
`if(infoException.contains(keys))`

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) :

`public boolean contains(CharSequence s)`

> Returns true if and only if this string contains the specified
>   sequence of char values. 
>   Parameters 
>   s - the sequence to search for

So here you want to find the sequence `keys` in `infoException` and not the inverse.

---

With `if(keys.contains(infoException))` you're actually searching if keys contains the sequence `"Could not connect to Item interfacecom.clns.exception.ItemNotFoundException: Could not find Item data"` which will return `false` because `keys` doesn't contain this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(keys.contains(infoException))
```

change this line to

```
if(infoException.contains(keys))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if (infoException.contains(keys))` instead of `if(keys.contains(infoException))`

So change your code to

```
String infoException = "Could not connect to Item interfacecom.clns.exception.ItemNotFoundException: Could not find Item data";
String keys = "ItemNotFoundException";
if (infoException.contains(keys))
    System.out.println("Exception found");
```

*Output:*

```
Exception found
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch your check around, it needs to be:

```
if(infoException.contains(keys))
```